# Do I need rebar and footing for a 1'4" tall 4" thick concrete wall?

Tags: concrete, walls, retaining-wall, rebar

I'm building a small concrete wall for an inground sandbox. The wall will be about 1'4" tall 4" thick and the longest 2 sides run just over 80" long, it is an L shape and the other sides are fairly short. Do I need rebar for this, or can I just use a concrete reinforced with fiber? Do I need footings?

Comment: Reenforced with fiber glass is the way I would go for a small wall like you want if you want metal I would use welded wire mesh standing on end with a 1 square overlap down the length.

Comment: Any concrete wall needs footings unless you want to watch it sink and lean for the next few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a kids sandbox I'm assuming they'll likely outgrow it at some point. When the time comes to remove it you won't want rebar in there. If it doesn't serve any other purpose than a border for the sandbox then I'd skip the rebar.

Comment: I'd skip the concrete, too. Why not treated lumber?

Comment: @isherwood can you get non-arsenic/safe treated lumber?

Comment: Lumber containing arsen*ate* hasn't been produced in the US for years. it never really was a concern anyway unless your children are prone to eating the furniture. If they are, concrete has been known to cause tooth loss in children who attempt to eat it.